# How to animate with delay TweenMax.to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gsap

I created an animation with TweenMax, that animate a div from 100% width of it's parent to zero. I have three divs next to each other, that are overlapping the image below. Now I would like that each `preload` div class will start some seconds after the previous one was triggered.

I try something like setTimeout, but I couldn't get it work. 
How can I achieve above?

CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aWVZXL

Comment: Do you want to remove one by one....?

Comment: Yes. So when the first div is finished with the animation, the next should be started, or when it is in the middle of it's animation, the other one will start. @MadhuMagar

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the script. Please refactor if you want.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var toBeAnimated;
var currentAnimat = 0;

$('.link').click(function() {
    toBeAnimated = $(".preloader");
    console.log('lets start animation');
    preload(toBeAnimated[currentAnimat]);
});

function preload(elem) {
    var elem = $(elem);
    var width = elem.outerWidth();
    // Tween out preload div
    TweenMax.to(elem, 1.4, {
        width: 0,
        right: 0,
        onComplete: function() {
            elem.remove();
            currentAnimat++;
            if(currentAnimat >= toBeAnimated.length) {
                console.log('Animation done');
            } else {
                preload(toBeAnimated[currentAnimat]);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

});

Comment: Thank you. This is what I want to achieve. One thing, is it also possible to animate in reverse order. This because I have had use rtl to position elements correctly in my layout.

Comment: You can... you have to reverse `toBeAnimated` before you call `preload(toBeAnimated[currentAnimat])`